# Why Does my EmailConfirmed property keeps reverting to false after updating and setting it to true

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a StApplications Class with a boolean property ConfirmEmai, my application sends a link to Confrim mail to new users and upon confirmation, i am setting the email confirmed property to true and updating and saving changes.

but i realised after a while i get this prompt upon login for a user who has confirmed their email that the email is not confirmed.

this Email is not confirmed prompt is set only when the email confirmed field for that user is set to false.

Please what are my doing wrong

I have tried so many ways to update that particular user ConfrimEmail property, at first it will and after a while revert back to false.

public IActionResult ConfirmEmail(int appId, string token)

```
    {




        if (appId == 0 || token == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ApplicationIndex", "Home");
        }



        else
        {

            var applicant =  _context.StApplications.SingleOrDefault(c => c.ApplicationId == appId);
            if (applicant.tokenProvided == token)
            {
                applicant.ConfirmEmail = true;
                //applicant = new StApplications { IsEmailConfirmed = true };
                var updatedApplicant = _ApplicationRepository.Update(applicant);
                //_context.StApplications.Update(applicant);

                if (updatedApplicant == true)
                {
                    return View();
                }
            }

            else
            {
                ViewBag.Invalidtoken = "Invalid";
                return View();
            }



        }
        return BadRequest();
    }
```

the commented out section is what i tried but all the same result, update to tru and then after a while revert to false

I Expect that the ConfirmEmail Action should set the emailconfirm propety to true and remain so without changing

Answer (score 0):

For you current code, you did not save the changes by calling `await _context.SaveChangesAsync();` after `_context.StApplications.Update(applicant);`.

In addition, you could try

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string userId, string code)
    {
        if (userId == null || code == null)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("/Index");
        }

        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{userId}'.");
        }

        code = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(code));
        var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code);
        StatusMessage = result.Succeeded ? "Thank you for confirming your email." : "Error confirming your email.";
        return Page();
    }
```